# Delete with subquery that produces two columns (in Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-delete

I have to delete a few records that match two columns calculated with a subquery.

I can properly see them with this query:

```
select * from user_assignments as ua, 
    (
        select user_assignments.user_id as uid, 
               job_selection as jid 
        from user_assignments
            join job_selections on job_id = jobs.id
            join data on job_selections.data_id = data.id
            where data.my_column IS NULL
    ) as sq
    where sq.uid = ua.user_id AND ua.job_selection_id = sq.jid;
```

This works, and I see the 7 assignments I want to delete.

However, deleting is not as easy as changing the SELECT by DELETE...

If I do:

```
delete from user_assignments as ua, 
    (
        ...
    ) as sq
    where sq.uid = ua.user_id AND sq.jid = ua.job_selection_id;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
```

I've tried quite an assortment of combinations, yet I can't get it to work. I imagine it must be quite simple, but I'm quite a newbie in SQL.

Basically, I have a subquery that properly produces two columns that I can use for a `SELECT FROM user_assignments` and now I want to `DELETE FROM user_assignments` the records that I know I can SELECT.

Any hints would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `in` or `exists`:

```
delete from user_assignments ua
where exists (select 1
              from user_assignments ua2 join
                   job_selections js
                   on ua2.job_id = js.id join
                   data d
                   on js.data_id = d.id
              where d.my_column IS NULL and
                    ua.user_id = sq.uid and ua.job_selection_id = sq.jid
             );
```

Comment: Oh... I just saw this answer when I posted mine. Thank you! It looks similar to what I actually ended up doing, and I'm sure this one is much safer, so let it be the _chosen_ answer. I trust you much more than I'd trust myself 

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I got it (I think).

Kuddos to this tutorial [this tutorial](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/delete-statement/delete-with-subqueries.php) and particularly, the section *SQL delete records using subqueries with alias*.

If someone else is interested, what I did was:

```
DELETE FROM user_assignments ua
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT user_assignments.user_id as uid,
           user_assignments.job_selection as jid
    FROM user_assignments
        join job_selections on job_id = jobs.id
        join data on job_selections.data_id = data.id
    WHERE data.my_column IS NULL
        AND ua.user_id = uid
        AND ua.job_selection = jid
)
```

This query also works fine with `SELECT * FROM user_assignments`